# does using quicksight on athena cost money per query like normal athena?

Tags: amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

I want my company to start use quicksight instead of dockered redash, but before I do I need to know something.
If I use quicksight on athena does it cost money for every query I ran in there like using athena normally or since its part of aws I only pay to use the quicksight service and the query fee is part of it?
Sadly I couldn't find an answer for it online

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you import data into SPICE then you shoudl be charged [per Gb](https://aws.amazon.com/quicksight/pricing/#SPICE) and per query hitting Athena based on the refresh frequency you have set up for the datasource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What format is your actual source data? You could load a number of formats directly into Quicksight without needing Athena to save the cost of using Athena and just use Quicksight SPICE instead.

Comment: My source data is  parquet files in s3. So can I load them without athena?

Comment: Unfortunately, parquet is not yet supported for direct imports annoyingly for quicksight. If you can put it in another format you will save some money duplicating the Athena cost.